# MAX(COUNT(*)) in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to take MAX of my count but it does not work, 
Oracle does not allow to deep aggregation..

this is results without MAX:

```
187 1   2
187 3   1
159 1   1
159 3   1
159 2   8
188 2   9
188 1   2
188 3   1
187 2   9



select tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id, max(count(*)) as usage
from tokens tt
left outer join token_xref ttx on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id
where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and ttx.template_id = 52
group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id
```

I also tried to put it in having max(count(*)); but did not work

Is there any way to get MAX of the COUNT() in one query and no inner select

I expect after MAX

```
187 2 9
159 2 8
188 2 9
```

**EDIT**

I have one more concern using analytic query 
instead of just guess which row to exclude if I have duplicates

```
MIN(tag_variable_type_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage) AS tag_variable_type_id
```

I assigned to my variable type "Priority" using decode function, so my guess would be 
`MIN(priority) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage) AS priority`, see  query

But I am again loosing my tag_variable_type_id..

anyway to keep it? I decode it back, but might be better way

```
 decode (MIN(priority) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage), 1,2, 2,1, 3,3) as typevar,



select token_id,    
   MIN(priority) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage) AS priority,
   MAX(usage) AS usage 
from ( select tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id,  
              decode(
                tt.tag_variable_type_id,
                1, 2, 
                2, 1, 
                3, 3  
              ) as priority,
              count(*) as usage 
       from tag_tokens tt 
       left outer join template_token_xref ttx on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id 
       where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and ttx.template_id = 52 
       group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id)
group by token_id;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect as the final output after MAX() - just a single row with a number 9 for usage?

Comment: just added my expectation to my post

Comment: I do not really avoid just do not know or could it be done without inner select

Comment: how do I apply MAX as outer select to get expected result?
need MAX based on first column but with information in second column

Comment: Why is the row with `8` to be returned? If I remember well, 8 is smaller than 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select token_id, 
   MIN(tag_variable_type_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage) AS tag_variable_type_id,
   MAX(usage) AS usage from ( select tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id, count(*) as usage from tokens tt left outer join token_xref ttx on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and ttx.template_id = 52 group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id ) group by token_id ;
```

Note1: MIN (tag_variable_type_id) is not necessarily correct, I just assume that it's functionally redundant, only required by the Oracle SQL syntax

Note2: There are other ways of writing the query without analytical functios, but this way is probably the most efficient

Comment: yes, this way work faster, but what does KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage) does?

Answer (score 2):

You need to match lines from your original result set with another query on the same result set that gets the max of usage.

We'll be using a `WITH` clause for clarity :

```
WITH result_count as (select tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id, count(*) as usage
    from tokens tt
       left outer join token_xref ttx on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id
       where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and ttx.template_id = 52
       group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id )
select result_count.token_id, tag_variable_type_id, max_usage
   from result_count   join  -- original result set
     (select token_id, max(usage) max_usage
        from result_count
        group by token_id) result_max on  -- result set with max usage
         result_count.token_id = result_max.token_id AND
         usage = max_usage ;
```

Now, if there are several `tag_variable_type_id` that reach the max, you'll get several lines for one `token_id` ; if you only need one you'll have to add an arbitrary condition.

Comment: This is the correct query if indeed you want several tag_variable_type_id's to be output when all of them match the max_usage - as opposed to the analytic query that I provided. If there can be (or you want) only 1 row to be output per token_id then my analytic query is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll just need to wrap another select around what you already have:

```
select token_id, max(usage) from (
 select tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id, max(count(*)) as usage
 from tokens tt
 left outer join token_xref ttx on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id
 where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3) and ttx.template_id = 52
 group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id
) 
group by token_id
```

Comment: Yes, but I am loosing tag_variable_type_id in this case, and I need it.. I do not need MAX column but first two required

Answer (score 0):

[ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) can be used to assign unique row number to each row.

```
select token_id,tag_variable_type_id,usage
  from(
       select tt.token_id token_id,
              tt.tag_variable_type_id tag_variable_type_id,
              count(*) as usage,
              row_number() over (partition by tt.token_id order by count(*) desc) as r
         from tokens tt left outer join token_xref ttx
              on ttx.token_id = tt.token_id
        where tag_variable_type_id in (1, 2, 3)
          and ttx.template_id = 52
        group by tt.token_id, tt.tag_variable_type_id
        )
 where r= 1;
```

- `order by count(*) desc` ensures highest count gets row number 1 and next highest row number 2 and so on.
- `partition by tt.token_id` ensures this numbering is reset for each group of token_id.

Use this row number in outer query to filter only those rows with row number 1.